# Trouble aligning a dropdown followed by textarea in HTML

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to achieve the following in HTML:
[image]

But apparently I'm having an issue where the textarea disturbs the alignment of the dropdown menu in which I'm getting this.

[image]

Why couldn't the dropdown element stay at the top in line with the top of the textarea like the first image? Everytime i increase the height of the textarea, it appears as if the dropdown is continuously sticking on the bottom left edge of the textarea.

Would appreciate some help on this as I'm trying to achieve the alignment as the first image above. Here is my attempt:

```css
.dd {
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<select id="d1" name="Addr" class="dd">
  <option value="Address1">Address</option>
</select>
<textarea id="addr_in"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap that dropdown and textarea inside `div` with `.container` class and apply flex layout with `align-items: flex-start` on that div.

`align-items: flex-start` css attribute will align all items on the cross-start line.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.dd {
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 250px;
  
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <select id="d1" name="Addr" class="dd">
    <option value="Address1">Address</option>
  </select>
  <textarea id="addr_in"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vertical-align: top.

```
.dd {
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
    height: 120px;
    width: 250px;
}
```